# Excel Calculate holidays taken based on 3 bits of criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

**EDIT START**
First of if you're reading this for the first time, below this edit section is my previous post.

I think the only way to get the results I want is to either create a script in vb or change my table design as Robin Mackenzie has mentioned in the comments below.

I have made a custom function for this purpose when I began to give up hope, after speaking to my friend he has decided he'd prefer some sort of input form to make adding data easier, so I'm going to limit the vb to the forms and change the table design so that I can use a formula.

Here is my custom function encase anyone ever needs such a thing.

http://pastebin.com/PDCGLJs4

The script isn't that big but I didn't want to add too much to this post, there are two variables in that script called newyears and christmas, those variables represent "dd/mm" the year is dynamic, and those two dates are excluded from the count, I also incremented the datediff by 1 since if an employee takes 24/02/2017 off, the datedif would come back 0.

Once I've made my changes I'll add my formula + anything to this topic as an answer.

**EDIT END**

So I've been wracking my brain trying to figure out how to do this with without VBA. I am creating an employee sheet that will contain payroll information and holiday's taken by each employee, I've got everything else done and fully dynamic where I need it, except I can't figure out how to extract the holiday data for each employee that fits within a two dates and how to calculate all of it.

[image: Here is an example of the employee holiday table]

[image: Here is an example of the payroll data]

So, I need to extract all holidays that are within the ranges specified in each week and then calculate them to get the days between the dates.

Example: In Week 1, there are 4 holidays by the same person on different dates (Amy Alpha), there is also an employee who takes 5 holidays that starts on week 4 and ends on week 5 (Elaine Echo).

Basically, I need to grab only the holidays taken within each week, so when it comes to Elaine Echo I need to only get 2 holidays for week 4 and 3 holidays for week 5, but when it comes to Amy I need to get the all her holidays within that week.

On top of this, I need to find out if the holidays are over a date that shop is closed, December 25th and 1st January.

I have no problems extracting information and I have no problems calculating what I need to calculate, but I can't seem to create a formula to do both, so here is what I've basically got at the moment.

The below code will check to see if 1st January or 25th December falls between our week, then it checks to see if date is also within our holiday range, if so it adds 1 or 2 which is then deducted from that holiday since the workplace is closed on that date

B18 is Holiday StartDate

C18 is Holiday EndDate

B4 is Week StartDate

D4 is Week EndDate

A6 is the start of the Employee names

I've also got the holiday table defined

Holiday_Table

Holiday_StartDate

Holiday_EndDate

```
SUM((IF(OR(AND((DATE(YEAR(B18),12,25)>=B4),(DATE(YEAR(B18),12,25)<=D4)),AND((DATE(YEAR(C18),12,25)>=B4),(DATE(YEAR(C18),12,25)<=D4))),"1","0"))+(IF(OR(AND((DATE(YEAR(B18),1,1)>=B4),(DATE(YEAR(B18),1,1)<=D4)),AND((DATE(YEAR(C18),1,1)>=B4),(DATE(YEAR(C18),1,1)<=D4))),"1","0")))
```

Next is the calculations for my dates, same cells as above for this example, and what it basically does is finds out if the Holiday StartDate is within the week, and if the Holiday EndDate is within the week, then it just either gets the date difference between the Holiday StartDate and EndDate, or the Work StartDate and Holiday Enddate, or the Holiday StartDate and Work EndDate, or finally gets the date difference between the start and end date of the work week.

```
IF((B18>=B$4)*(B18<=D$4),IF((C18>=B$4)*(C18<=D$4),SUM(C18-B18),SUM(D$4-B18)),IF((C18>=B$4)*(C18<=D$4),SUM(C18-B$4),IF((B18<=$B$4)*(C18>=$D$4),SUM(D$4-B$4),IF(B18>D$4,0,"errend"))))
```

So with this code, once it gets the total days, the other code will deduct 1 or 2 if the holiday falls on the 1st of January or 25th december.

There might be an easier way to do this with a formula, and I may have over complicated it, but at the moment I can't think of a way to

1. Extract the data based on the two dates and employee name.
2. Calculate all of them as well as deduct the dates
   the shop is closed.

I have tried to use if statements, index, countifs and match to get only the values for each employee, the employee names would be an example of this, but I'm not able to figure out a formula for holiday part.

Just incase it helps, here is my formula for my employee names.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Payroll_Table,MATCH( 0,IF(Payroll_StartDate>=$A$2,IF(Payroll_EndDate>=$A$4,COUNTIF($A$5:A5,INDEX(Payroll_Table,,1))),"")),1),"")
```

In this example, A2 is the start date and A4 is the end date for the payroll, this is how I get my range for the weeks as well as which employee's worked that week.

Hopefully someone can help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your holiday data based on something else ? If you had a long list of employee/ date pairs for every day they were on holiday this would be a heck of a lot easier.

Comment: Hey, @RobinMackenzie thanks for the reply, no, I have a few tables, one with employee names and pay rate, another for holidays and another for the payroll which is dates and hours worked... this form won't be used by me, but a colleague, so I wanted to make entering data as easy as possible, I didn't want him to have to enter each date, but I think if I want it as a formula it will have to be designed that way, and just create some sort of a user form to add all the dates to the table.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I have updated my topic and I'll be taking your suggestion to change the table layout so I can use a formula :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been reluctantly leaning towards this solution but Robin Mackenzie's comment swayed my decision to do so.

So before I continue, I just want to say that I have attached the excel sheet with some mock data in it, just in case anyone wants to take a look, it does contain scripts which are mostly for the userforms I have embedded in the overview sheet. I'd also like to thank Robin and Jared Clemence for their two cents on this matter, it was greatly appreciated.

Instead of having the holiday table with a start and end date, which I honestly still think would have been the best way to input the information, excel has bent me to its will and I now have 1 row for the holiday dates, this means that my table looks like this.

```
Name | Holiday
Emp1 | 21-Feb-17
Emp1 | 22-Feb-17
Emp1 | 23-Feb-17
```

and I just count it using the COUNTIFS function

A5 is Employee Name
B3 is Week Start Date
C3 is Week End Date

```
=COUNTIFS(tbl_holiday_name,"="&$A5,tbl_holiday_dates,">="&B$3,tbl_holiday_dates,"<="&C$3)
```

I omitted a lot of the code to make it easier to read, I can also include the two holiday periods for when the store is shut, which looks like this

```
tbl_holiday_dates,"<>"&DATE(YEAR(Overview!E2),12,25),
tbl_holiday_dates,"<>"&DATE(YEAR(Overview!E2)+1,1,1)
```

The Overview is a sheet name and E2 contains the date which marks the beginning of the new holiday year. The other option, instead of using a formula to ignore specific dates, I could instead add a blacklist to the forms which would ignore specific date when being entered into the table.

And Finally, here is a mock sheet, it is not complete but I think I've gotten rid of most if not all the bugs my formula's

[ShopSheetTemp.xlsm](https://app.box.com/s/j4lfdj8ya4jyys41mzdkfjs5qup6u0lm)

Answer (score 1):

Wow! You have taken on quite the task.  Naturally, my advice would have been to use VBA, but you have noted this is not an option. Here is the good news: you can do it, but it will be very complex.

Because you are implementing complex logic into cell based data, it is made most simple by creating a worksheet.  This is similar to what most government agencies do with tax submissions.  You will process data one step at a time and break it down into chunks, and the value from one row will be based on the values for the row above.

Worksheets like this should have an Excel Sheet that is separate from the main document so that you can hide all the data and calculations.

I would start by building a lookup table dynamically.

1. Create a new sheet in your workbook.
2. In the left most column, set the first value of your table equal to the start date of week1.
3. In the columns of each row below that, increment the date by 1 day until you reach the end of the week or the end of your total period (start with a single week and then expand.

Now you have a list of days in the week being considered.  Now in the next column of the table, your question becomes, did employee X have a holiday on this one day?

Because you are not using VBA, you will need to hard code these checks for every line of the Holiday History table, and you will need one sheet for each employee.

[image: Worksheet for Amy's Holiday]

In the above worksheet, I have tried to make my life easier by putting the employee name in cell B1.  This way, I can copy the working page and only change the employee name to update the table values.

In the range B3:G3, I compare the employee name in B1 with the name of the row I am checking in the holiday table.  Column B checks the data table on row Sheet1!A3:D3, and Column D checks the data table on row Sheet1!A5:D5. Both these rows are for Amy Alpha, so they result in TRUE.  The other rows result in FALSE, because the names do not match.

Beneath these values, I have nested IF statements:

1. If the value above is TRUE (this row matches the employee name, continue), otherwise output an empty string "" and move on.
2. ...nested...  Does the date in Column A fall between the start date and end date of my corresponding table row?  If yes, output 1 day, otherwise output 0 days.

The result is a table of values of 1's and 0's.  I sum each row and store that result in column H of my worksheet.  Note, that this allows me to check for errors and overlapping holidays, because it is possible using the table format that two rows contain overlapping holidays. Take for example if the start date of a holiday were entered with the wrong year, it would certainly overlap all the holidays before it, and the employee would have 2 holidays associated with a single date.

In column I, I check whether the date in column A matches one of the start dates for the weekly columns.  This check is not necessary, but I use it to help clean up the data in Column J so that I only display the data I am truly interested in.

Column J outputs a sum of the current row sum (column H) plus the six days that follow, making the sum of one week's worth of holidays.

Now, on Sheet1, I use a VLOOKUP() to pull out the value from column J based on the start date of the week.  My VLOOKUP for Week 1 is as follows for each employee (Note, I named my worksheets after the employees they model)

- `=VLOOKUP($B$13,Amy!$A$4:$J$38,10,FALSE)`
- `=VLOOKUP($B$13,Brian!$A$4:$J$38,10,FALSE)`
- `=VLOOKUP($B$13,Charlie!$A$4:$J$38,10,FALSE)`
- etc.

$B$13 contains the start date for Week 1, and the VLOOKUP searches for the row matching that date.  When that row is found, it moves to column #10, which matches Column J, and it returns that value.

For Week 2 my formulas are:

*`=VLOOKUP($D$13,Amy!$A$4:$J$38,10,FALSE)`
  *`=VLOOKUP($D$13,Brian!$A$4:$J$38,10,FALSE)`
  *`=VLOOKUP($D$13,Charlie!$A$4:$J$38,10,FALSE)`
  * etc.

My tabs have been copied, and each employee has their own tab... the result is this table (I did not bother with formatting or the Hours data):

[image: Holiday calculations by employee - no VBA]

You can download a copy of my example spreadsheet for closer review at this link, which I will leave active until March 31, 2017: [Example XLS Document - No macros](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1DVNlkykHATR19KVTFwNEF0TWM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm not at home yet but I will download your excel sheet, I sent my current document with a custom function and some other VBA scripts to my colleague and as expected he received some errors, took us a while to get it to work on that system, this is the reason I want to avoid VBA, because I know not all system will be set-up properly for it (even though they should), the document isn't government based or anything like that, it's a shop, but in the not so distant future there will be other shops under his management.

Comment: The goal was to make it as dynamic as possible, in the above post I only put the tables relating to my query, but I have a table of employee names and pay rates, as well as a status field where 1 = employed and 0 = not, the payroll sheet works perfectly with the payroll table, it grabs all the employee's within the week range as well as the pay rate and hours worked, it's only the holiday section that's causing me problems when trying to use formula's.

Comment: I am currently working on a table that will have employee names and all the dates they're on holiday, instead of having "Start Date" and "End Date", my current dilemma is how to get excel to separate the holiday periods so that for example, if Amy takes 2 holidays, 1st - 3rd and 6th-7th, I won't want that to show as 1 holiday, instead I need to figure out a formula that will do something like "if there is more than one day between these dates then start date are 1st + 6th and the end dates are 3rd and 7th, then again I'm not sure if I'll even need to worry about that.

Comment: Anyway, I will respond asap when I get home and look at your sheet. Again Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you have a lot on your plate. I'd be interested in knowing what errors your colleague had. The only errors that he should have received, possibly, is a version error, which can be fixed by using code that can be understood by older versions of VBA without using the advanced features implemented in newer versions.

Comment: As an alternative to using excel, if your colleage can be trained to output his excel data to CSV files, you might have a lot of luck writing quick command line tools that take a CSV file in, manipulate the data, and output a new file.  I recommend CSV only because it is easier to parse than native Excel files.

Comment: sorry for not getting back to you, I can't remember the error codes but he was using the same version as me, only difference was that the sys he tried it on was 32, mines is 64, but I could have sworn I tested it to ensure it worked, we ended up getting it working but I felt I could do better, so I've literally re-done the whole excel sheet so it's formula based, and I use VB for the forms.